# Method to reuse Environment variable definitions for both Run and Test Gradle tasks?

Tags: gradle, environment-variables, dry

***requirement***:

In selected Gradle sub-projects, we want to reuse environment variable definitions for `run`, `debug`, `test` etc. tasks.  For example, I thought the following would be the natural(??) way to go about things:

**`myproj.gradle`**

```
  test.dependsOn  defineEnvironement( mainClass )

  test.doFirst() {

      workingDir = "${testFolder}";
  }

  run.dependsOn  defineEnvironement( mainClass )

  run.doFirst() {

      workingDir = "${runFolder}";
  }
```

And where the `defineEnvironment()` task is declared in the `common.gradle` or the root project, something like ...

**`common.gradle`**

```
task defineEnvironement( type : JavaExec ) {

    println "-->  defineEnvironementVariables()"

    environment  "PROG_HOME",         "${RUN_PATH}";
    environment  "PROG_CONFIG_PATH",  "${RUN_PATH}/${cfgFolder}";

          :
}
```

***question***(s) ...

However that doesn't work at the moment.  There are various complaints about my "method signature" for the class.  Depending on what variations I run through for the

```
gradle myproj:test
```

... command.  I have moved that snipped around and used different approaches such as calling it via `doFirst()` and looking at different recepies from the web and stackoverflow.  Roughly this approach follows the steps from:

- [How to set an environment variable from a Gradle build?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36343921/108350)

Early alternatives rejected a 'method' becaue there is no environment in context -- Which makes sense, the `run` task must be an `Exec` typ.  In I think the key questions here are ...

- How do I pass-on the `test` and `run` tasks to the `defineEnvironement` task?
- And of course, it this the common (best?) practice approach?
- If not, what is the prefered method to reuse the  `defineEnvironement` steps and only need to specify and update them in one place?

I apologise it this is a bit basic.  I would think this kind of thing is what most projects (would like to) do in general by sharing common definitions/build code.