# How to pass environment variables to Gradle test task via IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

Spring 2.4.5.
Gradle 6.5.1.

There are placeholders in PostgreSQL connection string in `application.properties` file under test folder.

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${PG_HOST}:${PG_PORT}/
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.max-size=5
```

In order to make tests working, I've added the following lines to `build.gradle` file:

```
test {
    ...
    systemProperty "PG_HOST", System.getProperty("PG_HOST")
    systemProperty "PG_PORT", System.getProperty("PG_PORT")
    ...
}
```

So, I'm able to tun test via command line as follows:

```
./gradlew test -DPG_HOST=localhost -DPG_PORT=5432
```

Then, I decided to run Gradle test task via IntelliJ Idea Gradle pane.

[image]
I've added `PG_HOST` & `PG_PORT` as environment variables.

[image]

But the env variables are not being passed to Gradle test config, and test fail.

Any ideas on this matter?

Comment: if u would like to use environment variables you need to use System#getenv instead of System#getProperty.

Comment: Hi @AndreyB.Panfilov.
Tried getenv, but no luck as well

Comment: well, seems to be intellij issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-260217/Executing-gradle-in-IntelliJ-is-not-passing-environment-variables-eg-PATH-to-gradle

Comment: `-D` option is **not the same as environment variable property**. Also note that the variable you are specifying are for the Test process, not for the Gradle script usage. Better use `gradle.properties` to specify the properties for Gradle or also see this thread for means of setting the environment variables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322536/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-from-a-gradle-build