Environment files/values are not readable in intellij Idea
Am trying to setup a java project on my local machine, am new to java while trying to setup intellij idea, i can't read the environment files/values in the code
Attaching screenshots for reference

Sample code is written below
public class VRCoreAuthApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( "Testing env files " + System.getenv("DATABASE_NAME"));
        System.out.println( "Testing env files " + System.getenv("AWS_GIT_PROFILE"));
        System.out.println(System.getenv("NAME"));
        SpringApplication.run(VRCoreAuthApplication.class, args);
}

}

Output of the above code

Please note i have tried the answers of these question Setting up and using environment variables in IntelliJ Idea, it didn't work out for me. Am using mac

What IDE version and Run configuration do you use?

@y.bedrov
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.6 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-233.15026.9, built on March 21, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+1-b1087.23 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.4.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
ide.experimental.ui=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
com.jetbrains.space (233.15026.16)
Docker (233.15026.15)
Lombook Plugin (233.14808.21)
net.ashald.envfile (3.4.2)
Kotlin: 233.15026.9-IJ

Sorry, and what is run configuration type used? Please try to pass them via gradle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322536/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-from-a-gradle-build/36343921#36343921

@y.bedrov Sorry for the delayed reply, i fixed this issue, i have uninstalled all Intellij version then started freshly and it worked

@y.bedrov am getting the same error again, i dont know what went wrong, getting null error now
