DataSource defined dynamically in Grails 6.0.0
I have a Grails 6 application, it connects to PostgreSQL database. My data source is defined in application.yml but password for connection needs to be taken dynamically from external vault.
Tried this
https://guides.grails.org/grails-dynamic-multiple-datasources/guide/index.html
but it does not work for me.
Also, tried this in resources.groovy:
beans = {
    dataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create()
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:postgresql:...")
        return dataSourceBuilder.build()
    }

but it complains that "Bean definition is abstract". Other people had similar problem but questions were asked couple years ago and related to older version of Grails.

I think the easiest way would be to use a placeholder in yml logSql: "${DB_LOG_SQL:true}" and use the env variables

Ok, but I don't know how to do this. How to set such variable so it can be visible in application.yml with ${} notation?

Grails is able to pick up the application.yml from the classpath and automatically detect the datasource configuration there. And in YAML you can use the placeholder syntax like password: "${DB_PW:hellow}". which Grails also knows how to evaluate.

OK, but where I can define DB_PW?

DB_PW should be an env variable. You may want to write a script to extract those values from the vault and set then as env vars

Still don't know how to do this. There is a question about setting such env variable asked 8 years ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322536/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-from-a-gradle-build.
